# Convert list of coordinates to LineString within a dataframe

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a dataframe where one of the columns contains a list of x and y points and I would like to convert it to a spatial data frame but I am having trouble and not sure what to try next. My data frame looks something like this:

```
df['Location']
0     [(-80.58954, 44.60728), (-80.58942, 44.6073), ...
1        [(-81.09047, 44.74311), (-81.09004, 44.73771)]
2     [(-81.09004, 44.73771), (-81.09102, 44.75006),...
3     [(-81.09061, 44.7503), (-81.09036, 44.75045), ...
4        [(-81.08738, 44.75144), (-81.08759, 44.75657)]
                            ...
60    [(-80.48456, 44.35474), (-80.48454, 44.355), (...
61    [(-80.53522, 44.20374), (-80.53284, 44.20422),...
62    [(-80.52965, 44.20488), (-80.52937, 44.20494),...
63    [(-80.51611, 44.20489), (-80.51624, 44.2049), ...
64    [(-80.60715, 44.21462), (-80.60723, 44.21471),...
```

I have no problem when I take a single cell and convert it to LineString:

```
LineString(df['Location'][0]) 
<shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x000001DBD35D0128>
```

However when I try and try and use the apply function I get some errors that I cant seem to figure out.

```
df['Location'].apply(lambda x: LineString(df['Location']))
```

or

```
df['Location'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x), axis=1)
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "shapely/speedups/_speedups.pyx", line 86, in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linestring_from_py
    array = ob.__array_interface__
  File "D:\Python36\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5175, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python36\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4042, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2228, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "D:\Python36\Python36\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\linestring.py", line 48, in __init__
    self._set_coords(coordinates)
  File "D:\Python36\Python36\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\linestring.py", line 97, in _set_coords
    ret = geos_linestring_from_py(coordinates)
  File "shapely/speedups/_speedups.pyx", line 166, in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linestring_from_py
    assert n == 2 or n == 3
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `x` to `lambda` function instead of `df["Location"]`.

```
import geopandas as gpd
...


geometry = df['Location'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x))
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'} # For example

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
```

Answer (score 3):

What if you try like this :

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   LineString(index[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

I actually found my answer, it seems there is a bunch of coordinates that are points and they are not all LineStrings. I don't know if there is a way to input into a GeoDataFrame without first determining what type of geometry it is but I think that's a separate question.